# Jquery fires all element on click when I fire using the class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to customize my basicDay view in fullcalendar like if I click on the event it will slide down a div tag with some content. 
Here is my code.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view,calEvent) { 
if(view.name === 'basicDay') {
                            proj=event.title;
                            element.empty();
                            element.append('<div id="flip" class="flip1" onclick="slide()">'+proj+'</div>');
                            element.append('<div class="down" id="panel">\n\
                        Project Name: <input type="text" value="'+proj+'"/>\n\
                        Date: <input type="date" value="'+dt+'"/>');
                            element.append('</div>');
                            $(".fc-today").css("background", "white");

                        }
                    },
```

Here I am clearing task elements and add a custom div tag with the project name. If I have more than one event the Div tag will add dynamically.

The thing is, I need to slide down div with the class="flip1" and show the div with the class="down".

This is how I tried to do it.

```
function slide()
    {  
            $('.down').slideToggle("fast");

    }
```

The problem is if I have more than one event all the div tag is sliding down. But want to slide down the tag which I will click.Sorry for my bad English, please help me resolve this guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is expected behavior. jQuery comes up with an array when your select by classname. If you want to target a specific element, you will need to use its index. ...  `$(".myclassname").eq(index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to open `#panel` on clicking the the `#flip`
You can pass the context using `this` and then select the next immediate `#panel`

In dynamically created element

```
onclick="slide(this)"
```

Change in js

```
function slide(elem){  
   var getNextPanel = $(elem).next("#panel");
   getNextPanel.slideToggle("fast");
  }
```

Not tested but you can try this. Also note id like `panel` & `flip` cannot be same for all the dynamically created element, id need to be unique

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try it and let u know.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dynamic id to your element and then use a function like below

```
//id is your dynamic id and call this function on that element like `slide(this.id);`

function slide(id)
{  
    $('#'+id).slideToggle("fast");
}
```

Comment: I will try to do this and let u know bro. Thanks for ur suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your help bro. I used your technique its just working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You were right.  So here is your working example:

```
 function slide(id)
{  
        $('#'+id).slideToggle("fast");

}
```

Comment: $this is not working. The click is called from different div tag and i am sliding the different tag. Click event is called from 'flip' tag and i am sliding 'down' tag.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do this by the below code.

```
     var x=0;
eventRender: function(event, element, view,calEvent) { 
            if(view.name === 'basicDay') {
                                x++;
            element.removeClass("fc-event");
            element.addClass("day-event");
            element.children().addClass("day-event");
            proj=event.title;
            dt=new Date();
            dt=event.date;
            element.empty();
            element.append('<div id="'+x+'" class="flip1" onclick="slide(this.id)">'+proj+'</div>');
            element.append('<div class="'+x+'" id="panel">\n\
            Project Name: <input type="text" value="'+proj+'"/>\n\
            Date: <input type="date" value="'+dt+'"/>');
            element.append('</div>');
            $(".fc-today").css("background", "white");
             }
           },
```

and I wrote the function like this.

```
function slide(id)
    {  
            $('.'+id).slideToggle("fast");

    }
```

And this function also working fine.

```
function slide(id)
    {  
           // $('.'+id).slideToggle("fast");
            var getNextPanel = $('#'+id).next("#panel");
            getNextPanel.slideToggle("fast");

    }
```

If I need to improve my code further please suggest me guy's.Thank you for all your support guys.